# Е*у или Еб*ю – вот, в чём вопрос

Tags: обсценная-лексика, спряжение

Достаточно любопытная ситуация со словом **"ебать"**.

*Руб***ать** - *руб***аю**

*Брос***ать** - *брос***аю**

*Пин***ать** - *пин***аю**

*Гад***ать** - *гад***аю**

*Кат***ать** - *кат***аю**

*Игр***ать** - *игр***аю**

---

*Еб***ать** - *еб***у**, а не *еб***аю**

*Жев***ать** - *ж***ую**, а не *жев***аю**

Это исключения или как-то такая аномалия всё же объясняется?

Answer (score 5):

Ну уж коли спросили... Форма "ебу" скорее всего порождена инфинитивом "ебсти". В силу табуированности парадигм обеих форм четкое соответствие личных форм (и форм прошедшего времени) исходным неопределенным формам размылось, формы смешались. Особенно хорошо это видно на примере двоякой формы "ёб"/"ебал", первая из которых восходит к перфекту "ебсти", а вторая - к так называемому л-причастию (форма имперфекта, породившая современное прошедшее время).

Глаголы типа жевать, совать, давать, тоже порождающие "короткие" личные формы, связаны с совершенно другими грамматическими процессами, это для другого вопроса.