# Ты(,) чё(,) вовсю опупел и обурел? А?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, жаргон

Нужна запятая 1 и запятая 2?

> Ты(,) чё(,) вовсю опупел и обурел? А?!

Comment: А как вы сами думаете? Что вас затрудняет при решении этой задачи? Как вы ее решали?

Comment: Я точно думаю, что нужны запятые.

Comment: А почему спрашиваете, если знаете?  Вопрос-то несложный.

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр Знак цитирования в заголовке не убрали)

Comment: Эти глаголы разве не одно и то же означают? И почему *вовсю*, а не *вовсе*? Различия в словах не хотите видеть? Из *последних сил опупеть*, это что за бред?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

• Сначала переведём:
чё — что;
опупеть — сойти с ума, свихнуться;
обуреть — обнаглеть, наскочить, осмелеть, наброситься;
вовсю — с предельной силой, с максимумом усердия, изо всех сил (правильно — совсем).

• Потом поставим только одну запятую (№ 2):

*Ты чё, совсем опупел и обурел? А?!*
(Ты что, совсем свихнулся и обнаглел?)

> **1.** Слова ***что, а что, что же,*** обозначающие вопросы, и слова ***как, как же, что же,*** выражающие удивление, подтверждение, согласие и т. п., за которыми следует предложение, раскрывающее их конкретный смысл (после них делается пауза), отделяются запятой...

• Затем посмотрим на примеры из Нацкорпуса (для большей выразительности иногда ставится тире):

*— **Ты что,** совсем с дуба рухнул? — пригвоздила его Мария...* (Андрей Геласимов. Дом на Озерной);
*— Марсоид! **Ты что —** совсем с ума сошел?* (М.C. Аромштам. Мохнатый ребенок);
*— **Ты что,** совсем оборзела? — **Ты что,** совсем слетела с катушек?* (Татьяна Сахарова. Добрая фея с острыми зубками);
*— **Ты что,** совсем спятил? — налетела на Служкина Надя* (Алексей Иванов. Географ глобус пропил).

[Вопросительно-восклицательные слова](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=131#pp131) (Розенталь)

Comment: Ну не знаю!.. Чего минуснули-то? Разве ответ неправильный? Объясните, пожалуйста, в чем дело.

Comment: Мне бы что-нибудь из Мандельштама...  А на эту сленговую ругань смотреть надоело.  Минусовали, а не минуснули...

Comment: Я уж и так всё, что можно, понаисправляла — перевела, можно сказать, на приличный язык. Это ведь не мой личный лексикон — чего ж наказывать-то?

Comment: Я сразу и вопрос, и ответ.  Вопрос многим не понравился.  Его не исправлять надо было, а удалить. И сложности в нем никакой, Лео не может нужный материал в справочнике найти? Вся суть ответа: чё – это что.  Больше и сказать-то нечего. Не много...

Comment: Разве на надо полностью *чё* и *что* обособить? То есть *Ты, что/чё, совсем?*.

Comment: Наверно, можно, но по-другому. Например, так: *Ты!.. Что, совсем ошалел?!* Или так: *Ты чего? Совсем рехнулся?* Или как у Чивилихина: *— Я тебе... что... совсем не по душе?* Другие знаки нужны — не запятые.

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр Вы знаете, Леопольдище-мэтрище (если не нравится обращение, скажите), меня тут и носом ткнули (ну не Мандельштамы мы, к сожалению, — не каждому дано), и сказали, что вопрос ваш наипростейший, и предложили все и вся закрыть... Не буду больше упираться. Не нравится — вообще удалю. Не проблема. Вот здесь ещё посмотрите: *Какова синтаксическая роль оборотов с «что» и какая пунктуация при них?* Там *Sharon* почему-то было что сказать.

Comment: Ты что, с ума сошел?  Ты чё, с ума сошел.  Что-нибудь есть еще? Если только так: Ты! Что? С ума сошел? Эмоции хорошо выражены. Может, мне все-таки писателем стать?  У меня диалоги хорошо получаются. Коммуникативность, и все такое.

Comment: Да, диалоги у Вас неплохо получаются... А *что-нибудь ещё*, конечно же, есть — и не только у Вас. Я ранее уже предлагала автору возможные варианты. Всё простенько, правда?

Comment: А зачем предлагали? Вот вопрос: Нужна запятая 1 и запятая 2? Ответ: Нужна 2. И ссылка на Розенталя. Сложная задача? Вариантов-то нет. Ссылку можно в комментариях дать.  Вот заходят люди на сайт и видят на первой странице этот вопрос. Я бы сразу ушла. Наверное. Об этом тоже надо думать.

Comment: На сайте и другие вопросы есть, с более крепкими словцами. Никто даже не пытался их закрыть.  (https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461610/%d0%95%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%95%d0%b1%d1%8e-%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%b2-%d1%87%d1%91%d0%bc-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81)  (https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/467795/%d0%a1%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b2%d1%83-%d0%9f) А тут... Слова "чё" и "опупеть" имееются в толковом словаре. Закроем все и вся?